# My Wordpress plugin should create hierarchical URLs, how?

Tags: php, seo, wordpress

I have written a webshop plugin, that connects to a custom back-end filled with products via REST, and renders the products in a page. The backend REST api supports hierarchical categories , and then in the leaves, there are the products. So users can click through Cat1 -> subcat -> sub sub cat -> product X

This works. But i would like the urls then to be /categories/cat1/subcat/subsubcat/, which I can't get working.

My current architecture is like so: I have a page with slug 'categories', and in that page i have this shortcode: [webshop_categories]

My plugin does a curl call to the backend in PHP, and renders the products. It does so by observing the URL (non hierarchical, but say: /categories/123/) get the category ID, and then fetch the subcategories and products of that category ID.

Now for SEO purposes i'd like to have hierarchical urls.

This whole thing works, because if i create /categories/123, wordpress will go to that page,find the shortcode, and execute it.

If i however would've gone to /categories/myCat/123/mySubCat/345, it will try to find a page with slug mycat, yielding an 404.

Can I prevent wordpress from doing this?

Hopefully I explained it somewhat clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your plugin to handle determining if a URL is to be handled. I do this with a proprietary plugin that I wrote.

If your plugin is to handle a URL, you will want to look into:

```
add_action('template_redirect', array(&$this,'template_redirect'));
public function template_redirect(){
    global $wp_query;
    if($wp_query->is_404){
        $wp_query->is_404=false;
        $wp_query->is_archive=true;
    }
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
    //function to render your output here
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Ah this is an interesting angle I haven't tried yet. Will try this, thanks!